# DocuSign Envelope Webhook - JSON Format

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the [eventNotification](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) property when creating an envelope to be signed to set a per envelope webhook to receive notifications when the envelope is completed. I believe you can now specify the data format so you can change this to JSON from the default XML data format.

I've looked through the docs here and can't see anywhere to specify the data format to be JSON for a per envelope setting here.

Here's an example of my eventNotification details:

```
{
    "envelopeEvents" : 
    [
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode" : "completed"
        }
    ],
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion" : "false",
    "includeDocumentFields" : "true",
    "includeDocuments" : "false",
    "requireAcknowledgment" : "true",
    "url" : "https://acme.com/myWebhook.php"
}
```

Is there something I can add here to specify the webhook to send a JSON payload instead of XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json payloads are coming later this year. Only xml at this time, sorry

Comment: When we can expect JSON payload to be available for Docusign webhook?

Comment: JSON payloads have started limited testing. Contact your DocuSign support or sales person.

Comment: @LarryK Are JSON payloads out now ? Pls guide

Comment: Yes! Available now for all developer accounts. JSON notifications are also being ramped for production accounts. Should be all production accounts by end of Feb, 2021. Contact customer service if you need a production account sooner.